# How to get the re-occurrence count of an item in an IList? (Without Immutable in loop)

Tags: c#, linq, ilist

Hey guys I feel like this is a pretty simple question but I cannot find the answer. I have an IList with a bunch of items in it. And I want to count how many items are duplicated(This IList will have a lot of duplicated). So if the list has 'apple' in it 20 times and 'bannana' in it 30 times I want to put those into an associative array with the name as the key and the count as the value. I am currently doing it with this....

```
        var summary = new Dictionary<string,int>();

        foreach (myModel.Row in model.items)
        {
            if (summary.Count == 0 || !summary.ContainsKey(row.ItemTitle))
            {
                summary.Add(row.ItemTitle, 1);
            }
            else
            {
                summary[row.ItemTitle] += 1;
            }
        }
```

so model.items is an IList that contains Row.

The problem with this is that in the else I am incrementing an immutable in a loop, so I know there is a better way.

Thanks in advance for the help.

### edit

What I mean by no immutable in a loop is I am trying to avoid this `summary[row.ItemTitle] += 1;` and the negative performance implications of it. If there are any.

Comment: Not sure what this statement "I am incrementing an immutable in a loop" relates to. What are you trying to avoid? (Note that `summary[row.ItemTitle] += 1;` is simply short version of `var v = summary[row.ItemTitle]; summary[row.ItemTitle] = v + 1;`)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I am trying to avoid, the negative implications of incrementing an immutable in a loop. I am under the impression that when you increment an immutable in a loop, you are going to return a new object each time and that there are negative impacts on performance because of that.

Comment: There is no immutable here; your code is perfectly correct and I would expect it will run faster than the accepted answer.

Comment: @redtuna this `summary[row.ItemTitle] += 1;` is not inrecmenting an immutable? Since the dictionary is an int, and int's are immutable? Maybe I have a missunderstanding of immutables.

Comment: @recneps you probably should read on value types in C#/.Net. While your concern is somewhat valid its performance characteristics (especially for small value types like `int`/`double`/`DateTime`) are much less dramatic.

Comment: @recneps: Incrementing an int is a fast operation. They are not even objects - as Alexei's trying to tell you, they are "value types" and they are very much mutable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use LINQ [`GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx) to get the result:

```
var summary = model.items.GroupBy(x => x.ItemTitle)
                         .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

Comment: Goddamn your sudo typing skills... +1.

Comment: +1... @recneps - can you please update title of your questions so it is clear what "without immutable in a loop" means? This answer does use very similar data structure than your code (also much more complicated than necessary for your code, but clearly more readable/likely to work correctly).